# Squirtle vanished from my Pokemon Go list?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know and understand that Pokemon Go has major issues right now, in regards to server overloads etc with its grand opening. However, I am currently freaking out because two of my Squirtles have vanished from my captured Pokemon list! I caught one 2 days ago and one earlier today.

What's stranger is that my Charmander has magically changed its own name to Chinchilla somehow as well! I've only noticed it now after managing to log on (after a few hours with the servers being overloaded).

Has anyone else experienced this? Should I relax and wait till tomorrow to double check?

---

**Updates:**

I have the same situation as last night. I've learnt to accept it but I'm hoping to maybe find another Squirtle some day... And I renamed my Charmander back. Only my partner lives with me and he doesn't use it so I doubt he would have played around with it.

Squirtle appeared again, and I managed to capture one to make up for the missing 2, and luck would have it that I managed to catch a Wartortle too!

Comment: That's certainly odd. I don't have any Charmanders, but all of my Squirtles are accounted for. Perhaps close the game and try again? Sounds like some data was crossed up.

Comment: I'm trying but of course I can't get back on again... according to yesterday I was able to get back online at 2am so I'll wait for an hour or so to check...

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but did anyone borrow your phone? Pokemon could disappear due to bugs I guess, but being renamed is a little more than unusual...

Comment: This really looks like someone has/had access to your account.

Comment: Morning everyone! (mornings and afternoons are all clear for Pokemon here!) well it's the same situation as last night. I've learnt to accept it (which was hard) but I'm hoping to maybe find another Squirtle some day... And I renamed my Charmander back to Charmander... Only my partner lives with me and he doesn't use it so I doubt he would have played around with it, also I think he might have told me in my screaming tantrum of panic when I first noticed the mishap! I hate that anytime after 9pm anything could happen and I wouldn't know...

Comment: Well, as I thought Squirtle appeared once again this evening so I managed to capture one to make up for the missing 2! Also, luck would have it that I managed to catch a Wartortle too!